# Accessing python module for QGIS 3.0 topology checker from Python script?

Tags: qgis, python, topology

There is a similar question [Access QGIS Topology Checker from Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267788/access-qgis-topology-checker-from-python), however this user was wanting to run the topology tool while I want to import certain rules. For example in arcgis

> arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(for_validation, "Must Not Self-Overlap (Line)", nfc)

I saw this question about [accessing qgis plugins from python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/accessing-qgis-plugins-in-python). So I know I need to import the module, but I'm unsure the name of the module, or if it is written in C++ so importing into python directly is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible (as of 3.0) - that functionality isn't exposed to the python bindings.

Comment: Is it possible in 2.18?

Comment: No, I mean it's not possible up to 3.0 (but for future reference it may have been added in a later version)

Comment: Oh I see. I'll post a follow up question in a separate thread then seeing if I could scratch write a code for same functionality.